# Informatica routers

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have two sources A source B
Source A passes through a drug lookup and a router to see if the NDC is present and if not goes to either a present table or a nonpresent table.
Source B does the same but only looks for GCN number if it is present then it goes to a GCN present table or a gcn not present table.
I am currently using in Group filters
    `ISNULL(NDC_DRUG_CODE_LOOKUP)` 
    `NOT ISNULL(NDC_DRUG_CODE_LOOKUP)` 
    `ISNULL (GCN_CODE_out_LKP)` 
    `NOT ISNULL(GCN_CODE_out_LKP)` 
the problem is that when the lookup and GCN or NDC  code match it's not routing properly 
So my question is should I use two different sorters or is there a better way to code this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! The current question  which states your concerns about the code, is not really visible :) . Please edit it to the site standard https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , Please see How to get the best value out of stackoverflow: Asking Questions for guidance on writing good question .

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple sorters is not the right option because it reduces the performance. Not sure exactly about your requirement, but I hope below is what you are expecting. Use the condition in router in such a way,

```
ISNULL(NDC_DRUG_CODE_LOOKUP) AND
NOT ISNULL(NDC_DRUG_CODE_LOOKUP) AND
ISNULL (GCN_CODE_out_LKP) AND
NOT ISNULL(GCN_CODE_out_LKP)
```

If the condition is not working the issue would be with your lookup. Try creating an output target for each look up and test the scenario.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Pls note, router will produce row whatever conditions met. So you need to be very specific for each scenarios. Please pass only chosen rows. Jim above gave example for group 1. Similar condition should be put for group #2, 3,4.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Unconnected lookup , Call twice with GCN and NDC , And create four flags in single router and route them as per your requirement ...And one more suggestion if you are using ISNULL in router or any transformation , try to default to some like nvl in oracle, the reason is sometime it takes null both side it does not match..

Hope this helps...